# Different URLs when calling the base_url() function

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I have a PHP file with the following content:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/example1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var base_url = '<?php echo @base_url(); ?>';</script>
........
<input type="hidden" id="testvpn" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/example.js"/>
........
```

When I try to open the page locally, everything's ok:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/example1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var base_url = 'http://example.com/';</script>
........
<input type="hidden" id="testvpn" value="http://example.com/js/example.js"/>
........
```

When I try to open the page over web vpn, I want to see:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mywebvpn.com/+CSCO+numbers++/js/example1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var base_url = 'https://mywebvpn.com/+CSCO+numbers++/';</script>
........
<input type="hidden" id="testvpn" value="https://mywebvpn.com/+CSCO+numbers++/js/example.js"/>
........
```

But I get:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mywebvpn.com/+CSCO+numbers++/js/example1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var base_url = 'http://example.com/';</script>
........
<input type="hidden" id="testvpn" value="http://example.com/js/example.js"/>
........
```

P.S. Framework - codeigniter. Server side - PHP,MYSQL,APACHE. 
P.P.S. Configuring the webvpn service is not my job. Could it be a problem with webvpn?

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .=str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Comment: Please show how you are setting your base URL in your config file. Without that piece of knowledge, it's just guessing what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

### base_url()

Returns your site base URL, as specified in your **config file**.

---

Check if you overwrite config with that data. If not then it just caching, but if this is a miracle and it's return different values you can always do:

```
<?php
$bUrl = base_url()
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $bUrl?>js/example1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var base_url = '<?php echo $bUrl?>';</script>
........
<input type="hidden" id="testvpn" value="<?php echo $bUrl?>js/example.js"/>
```

Comment: Then it caching. Because printing same variable and getting different values is impossible. Maybe CI cache maybe server cache. Do you have code online to give us a link?

Comment: No, it is corporate server. I can not give access.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use base_url() to load JS and CSS files, I will show you how I use it.

CSS:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url('css/style.css')?>">
```

JS:

```
 <script src="<?=base_url('js/jquery.js')?>"></script>
```

Please note that I'm using short_tags, so depending on your php.ini, the exact copy/paste might not work.

I've found this solution to be the best, since you give the files the absolute path, so I never have issues where some server setups cannot locate files.

Comment: base_url() return different urls in different situations. This is problem.

Comment: How is your base_url defined in the config.php file?